# Difficulty resolving errors with imports in Javascript

Tags: javascript, module, xstate

I am new to JavaScript and vscode and getting it set up has been more difficult than any other language I have used at work.
When I run the code (in Test.js):

```
    var msg = 'here';
    console.log(msg);
    import { Machine, interpret } from 'xstate';
```

I get a error saying that I must use import to load ES module. I have looked at similar StackExchange threads to no avail despite attempting those fixes. Any help and readable resources are appreciated. Thanks.

Specific error debug printout:

```
Waiting for the debugger Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `import` line at the top.

Comment: That does not fix it, even absent the two other lines.

Comment: Did you install xstate first?